# Trie and Hash Array Mapped Trie comparison

Tags: data-structures, trie

There two similar data structure `Trie` abd `Hash Array Mapped Trie` wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie):

> A hash array mapped trie[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie) (HAMT) is an implementation of an
>   associative array that combines the characteristics of a hash table
>   and an array mapped trie.

My problem is next - i can't get why we need for `Hash Array Mapped Trie` while we have `Trie` which works on searching elements for O(1) and does `Hash array mapped trie` is more efficient than `TrieMap`, if it's true?

Comment: What made you think that trie's search takes O(1)? As stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), lookup takes O(m) where m is the length of a key.

Comment: @ karastojko maybe i am wrong, but when i read scala documentation about `TrieMap`, i found notes that it works for O(1), in due to the fact that `TrieMap` is based on `Trie`, i supposed that it works for O(1)

Comment: TrieMap [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/concurrent/TrieMap.html) claims it is based on [Ctrie](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~prokopec/ctries-snapshot.pdf) which is kind of [Hash tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree_(persistent_data_structure)), thus it is not Trie.

Comment: @karastojko thx, i was in misunderstand